# iphone:Extraneous Error in NSLog

Tags: iphone, xcode

when i run my app it gives me following error like Extraneous ')' before ';'

here is my NSLog which gives an error:

```
     NSLog(@"• Init page details for the book pages");
```

Comment: check out your above statements....or please provide some detailed code...the statement you have posted here is not giving any error to me...

Comment: Did you copy that line of code from a website? Try to remove that NSLog from your code and write it again by hand. I had similar errors caused by code that was copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have an extra `" ) "` in your expression or in earlier line . But I tested your code and didn't give any error.

Answer (score 3):

Your code didn't give me any errors as well. But if you still getting error, try to clean the code with shift+command+K and compile again or you should try stirngwithFormat for final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the only line of code in your app?  If so, try running it without the dot.  It might be causing the problem.

Edit: Tested, and does not give me an error.  So it is not the dot... do you have any other code in this app?

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't give me any errors as well, but just in case try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"• Init page details for the book pages");
```

Because NSLog() actually expects a format.